# Buttons in Alert dialog not working

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, android-intent

Okay so im originally working on putting attachments on my app, but first i need to get my dialog buttons to work.  Help please i really do not know what i need to do to get my buttons functional.

```
Attachment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    final CharSequence[] items = { "Picture", "Video", "Audio" };

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SMS.this);
                    // Read Update
                    builder.setTitle("Attachment");
                    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            if (items.equals("Picture")) {
                                Intent nextScreen1 = new Intent(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        FirstLoginActivity.class);
                                startActivity(nextScreen1);
                            }
                            if (items.equals("Video")) {
                                Intent nextScreen1 = new Intent(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        FirstLoginActivity.class);
                                startActivity(nextScreen1);
                            }
                            if (items.equals("Audio")) {
                                Intent nextScreen1 = new Intent(
                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                        FirstLoginActivity.class);
                                startActivity(nextScreen1);
                            }
                        }

                    });

                    builder.create(); // <-- See This!
                    builder.show();
                }

            });
        }
```

I dont get errors but it doesnt do anything.

Comment: Do you get any response from your buttons? Meaning if you put a log in them, do they appear ?

Comment: Is dialog box is showing up properly??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about replacing your `OnClick()` by this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    switch(which){
    case 0: // Picture
        Intent nextScreen1 = new Intent(
                getApplicationContext(),
                FirstLoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(nextScreen1);
        break;
    case 1: // Video
        Intent nextScreen1 = new Intent(
                getApplicationContext(),
                FirstLoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(nextScreen1);
        break;
    case 2: // Audio
        Intent nextScreen1 = new Intent(
                getApplicationContext(),
                FirstLoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(nextScreen1);
        break;
    }
}
```

Actually, if you don't want to use my suggestion above, you just need to correct your `if statement` like this:

change: `(items.equals("Picture")) to (items[which].equals("Picture"))`

Comment: Good eye, I could barely notice that.. haha :D that would have been quite obvious if logs were used to detect this of course, but who logs? really *facepalm*